# Unable to create new directory in perl with permission 777

Tags: permissions

I am trying to create a directory which should be writable to by everyone
this is the type of command I am creating the directory with
if(! -e "/mnt/imports/user"){
mkdir("/mnt/imports/user", 0777) or throw("Couldn't make /mnt/imports/user $! ");
}
but this is the privileges i get for the directory
drwxr-xr-x 2 lec ensembl 8192 Jun 4 15:15 briggsae_new_2 
while directory mnt has the 755 permission and imports has the 777 permission.
does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

umask is 0022 on your system.  You could do:

```
 if(! -e "/mnt/imports/user"){ mkdir("/mnt/imports/user") && `chmod 777 /mnt/imports/user`}
```